# Exchange 2013 - Archive mailbox empty/not updating

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, archiving, exchange-2013

I'm using Exchange 2013 in our environment and I am doing a test for a user with emails older than 5 years in their mailbox. I used the following PS command:

```
Enable-Mailbox "Username" -Archive -ArchiveDatabase "ExistingDatabaseName"
```

The database is separate from the one their normal user account is on.

The archive command appears to have worked as they now see an "archive" folder on the bottom of OWA and a "Online Archive - username@domain.com" mailbox in their Outlook client.

The problem is that there is no data in this folder. I'm assuming there's something I'm supposed to do with retention tags/policies (currently all users are on the default MRM policy). I thought the default was to move everything older than 2 years to the archive mailbox.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Edit: I verified the user is using the Default MRM policy and has those settings. There is a "Default 2 year move to archive" rule with type "Default" and retention period of 730 days and action of "archive" in that rule. I assume that should take effect?

Edit2: EMS `get-mailbox name -archive | get-mailboxstatistics | fl name, *size*` shows that the archive mailbox has ~10GB in it but after restarting outlook the image looks like this still:[image]

All folders are empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user has archive enabled, and assigned to the archiveDatabase, you need to make sure it's configured for MRM as you've stated. The archiving is then processed by the Managed Folder Assistant which should process all mailboxes on a mailbox server within a one day by default. (I hope you are seeing some result by today since your initial post was 18hrs ago)

You can verify the Managed Folder Assistance by checking the ManagedFolderWorkCycle attribute for your mailboxserver
`Get-MailboxServer | Format-Table name,ManagedFolderWorkCycle* -Auto`
 You can also trigger it for the user by PS 
`Start-ManagedFolderAssistant -Identity username@domain.com`

You can find more information about Configuring Managed Folder Assistant and Messaging Records Management Procedures here
[Configure the Managed Folder Assistant](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123958%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to set a scheduled time for this task to happen? Say 1-2am on each local mailbox server? @Lex I'm waiting to hear back that the process worked. From EMS I see that the archive mailbox has a size on it but the last time we checked the "Archive" in Outlook only showed the deleted items and search folders. Once confirmed I'll mark you as answer :)

Comment: It looks like we're still outta luck. Updated question with more info.

Comment: To clarify after your edit2. The archive mailbox is only archiving this user account and it has been bloated to 10Gb while you're not seeing any folders within this mailbox?

Comment: yes, I ran a get mailbox -archive for the user, checked the size, and it was 10GB. I had him restart Outlook and expand the folder and it't that image. Don't know why it's not showing any content? It could still be growing but I'll have to wait til tomorrow to find that out. Any idea on average time to have those created?